# git: как закрепить жесткий откат в удаленном репозитории?

Tags: git

В мастер случайно была влита (git push) ветка с другого сервера параллельной разработки. Локально удается сделать жесткий откат (git reset --hard), но залить его удаленно через git push не удается, потому что такой откат не считается изменением. Как закрепить его удаленно или откатить так, чтобы зафиксировать это на удаленном сервере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push --force` (он же `git push -f`)

Comment: Благодарю, не знал о такой опции. А как другому человеку теперь правильно сделать pull, чтобы этот откат зафиксировался и у него?

Comment: @Mik А вот тут уже сложнее. Если у него есть какие-то изменения, то сначала их надо сохранить. Или кинуть их в отдельный бранч, или используя git stash/pop. После чего ему так-же нужно сделать reset (`git reset --hard origin/<branch>`)

Comment: @Milk А вообще, раз вы не одни работаете, над бранчем - не следует делать операции с --hard/--force/rebase. В вашем случае надо было делать revert (не смотря на лишние коммиты)